# Java absolute file path not giving the desired path

Tags: java, file, path, directory, absolute-path

I have created a folder 'Maths' at /home/vamshi/Documents/Eval/Files/standard6/Maths/ and i have put some files in it.
They are hello.txt, world.txt

Now, i have used this java code to traverse the directory

```
    System.out.println("DIRECTORY PATH IS :"+path);


    File f = new File(path);
    System.out.println("DIRECTORY ABS PATH IS :"+f.getAbsolutePath());
    if( f.isDirectory() )
    {
        String[] subNote = f.list();
        for(String filename : subNote)
        {
                File tempFile = new File(filename);
                System.out.println("FILE PATH:"+tempFile.getAbsolutePath());

        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Its not a directory!");

    }
```

Output is :

DIRECTORY PATH IS :/home/vamshi/Documents/Eval/Files/standard6/Maths/

DIRECTORY ABS PATH IS :/home/vamshi/Documents/Eval/Files/standard6/Maths

FILE PATH:/home/vamshi/workspaceNew/Server/GUI_Version_Netbeans/server/hello.txt

FILE PATH:/home/vamshi/workspaceNew/Server/GUI_Version_Netbeans/server/world.txt

How is this possible?
How come the files inside Maths directory have the Netbeans project absolute path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a new file using just the file name, this creates the file in the default directory.  In this case, the file is put into "/home/vamshi/workspaceNew/Server/GUI_Version_Netbeans/server/"

Instead of giving it just the file name:

```
File tempFile = new File(filename);
```

Give it the desired path AND the file name, like so:

```
File tempFile = new File(path + filename);
```

This should create the file and put it into the desired location.

Comment: I would like to get the path names of all the files in the directory. Is there any way with out creating a file?

Answer (score 2):

[`File#list()` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list%28%29) states

> Each string is a file name rather than a complete path.

In other words, for a directory `File maths`

```
/home/vamshi/Documents/Eval/Files/standard6/Maths/
```

where the directory contains

```
abc.txt (file)
123.json (file)
/home (directory)
```

Then this code

```
maths.list();
```

will return a `String[]` containing

```
["abc.txt", "123.json", "home"]
```

These names have no relation to the `File` above. When you create new `File` objects from these `String` names, their absolute paths are resolved relative to the current working directory.

In Java 8, do

```
    Stream<Path> paths = Files.list(Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath());
```

to get a `Stream<Path>` containing all the absolute paths of files inside your directory.

Comment: I would like to get the path names of all the files in the directory. Is there any way with out creating a file?

Comment: @Vamshi In Java 8, use `Files.list(Path)`. See my edit.